# Import posts assigned "Uncategorized" category by default

Tags: wordpress, import, export

I have one xml file that contains posts (default WordPress posts) and I want to import it with another WordPress setup.

I already double check everything as remove default sample page, hello world posts and "Uncategorized" category term from xml file.

But, when I am importing that file with another WordPress site then by default new imported posts connecting to "Uncategorized" category.

Can anyone guide me, how can I remove that thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the same archive file a second time it removes the uncategorized category on all posts with another category.